# dowload maven dependency of a local or global repo without pom.xml

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I need to download files who are stored in various maven repo (sometimes global, sometimes in local) but I'm not in a maven project, so I don't have a pom.xml

also the solution
org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.1:get

don't work because I don't have a pom.xml.

edit : I still have the issue with the new version and all the args !

Comment: The idea using maven-dependency-plugin works of course but you have to give all informations on command line.. (Apart from that I would use a more recent version https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/get-mojo.html)...

Comment: I still have  The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory

Comment: Read my answer.....

Answer (score 0):

Please read the documentation fully and understand it cause you don't have to have a project which means having a `pom.xml` to execute

```
empty-project$ ls -al ~/.m2/repository/junit
ls: /Users/khmarbaise/.m2/repository/junit: No such file or directory
```

Checking that the project I use does not has any file nor a `pom.xml`

```
empty-project$ ls -la
total 0
drwxr-xr-x   2 khmarbaise  staff   64 Jun 15 14:28 .
drwxr-xr-x  12 khmarbaise  staff  384 Jun 15 14:28 ..
empty-project$
```

Now calling `dependency:get` goal of maven-dependency-plugin:

```
empty-project$ mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.1:get -DartifactId=junit -DgroupId=junit -Dversion=3.8

[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------< org.apache.maven:standalone-pom >-------------------
[INFO] Building Maven Stub Project (No POM) 1
[INFO] --------------------------------[ pom ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.1:get (default-cli) @ standalone-pom ---
Downloading from nexus: http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/junit/junit/3.8.1/junit-3.8.1.pom
Downloaded from nexus: http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/junit/junit/3.8.1/junit-3.8.1.pom (998 B at 13 kB/s)
Downloading from nexus: http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/junit/junit/3.8.1/junit-3.8.1.jar
Downloaded from nexus: http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/junit/junit/3.8.1/junit-3.8.1.jar (121 kB at 6.7 MB/s)
[INFO] Resolving junit:junit:jar:3.8 with transitive dependencies
Downloading from nexus: http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/junit/junit/3.8/junit-3.8.pom
Downloaded from nexus: http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/junit/junit/3.8/junit-3.8.pom (744 B at 106 kB/s)
Downloading from nexus: http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/junit/junit/3.8/junit-3.8.jar
Downloaded from nexus: http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/junit/junit/3.8/junit-3.8.jar (122 kB at 8.1 MB/s)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.118 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-06-15T14:33:23+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

That will download the artifact and place into your local cache.

which you can check afterwards:

```
empty-project$ ls -al ~/.m2/repository/junit
total 0
drwxr-xr-x    3 khmarbaise  staff    96 Jun 15 14:33 .
drwxr-xr-x  119 khmarbaise  staff  3808 Jun 15 14:33 ..
drwxr-xr-x    4 khmarbaise  staff   128 Jun 15 14:33 junit
```

All docs of maven plugins tell you if you require a project for example this https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/analyze-mojo.html  is a goal which needs a project (in other words a `pom.xml` file)...

> Attributes:
>
> Requires a Maven project to be executed. Requires dependency
>   resolution of artifacts in scope: test. Since version: 2.0-alpha-3.
>   Invokes the execution of the lifecycle phase test-compile prior to
>   executing itself.